# Is there any way of converting Powerpoint diagrams into Visio?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio

Is there a way of converting a diagram in Powerpoint 2016 to Visio 2016?

I have drawn a big complex diagram in Powerpoint and feel now that it would be better to continue working on it in Visio. However I seem to only be able to paste the diagram as an image into Visio :(

Comment: I no longer use Visio, so pardon if this is totally outdated, but:  can Visio import EMF or WMF?  PPT can save to both of those formats.

Comment: See the answer to do this in 30 seconds below as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may try after having copied and pasted into Visio, where your diagram appears as an image to ungroup. This works fine with MS 365 and does not require any additional application.

Comment: This is the right answer.  I added a separate answer to format the displayed steps below...

Answer (score 3):

As Detlef Huss mentioned above, his process works.  It's super simple to convert objects in PowerPoint to Visio without needing a 3rd party tool at all.  (This may be why they abandoned updating the Flowchart Converter Plug in after 2010.)

Here's the steps to do it in 30 seconds:

1. In PowerPoint 2016, on the slide you want to copy, enter editing mode (if not already editing).
2. Use Control-A to select all objects
3. Use Control-C to copy all objects to clipboard
4. Open Visio 2016 to a blank document
5. For convenience, change to "Design" Tab and change Orientation to Landscape (since most PowerPoint presentations are landscape)
6. Use Control-V (nothing special)
7. Right click the Image and select "Group -> Ungroup"
8. Bam...all the objects are there in Visio!

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, there is no native format that can be imported except Autocad.
The older versions circa 2000 had more options, I am currently working with Visio2013.

My solution has been to import the diagram as an image, which can then be set as a background layer, then replicate in Visio over the top and delete the image.

Comment: Try right clicking the pasted image and selecting "Group -> Ungroup".  No need to create objects by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Though not perfect, there exists a tool that might serve you: [Flowchart Converter](http://www.visio.jp/dl/us/flowconverter/index.html).

The tool is not updated since 2010 so I'm not sure how it will behave with PP 2016 and V 2016. If you have problems, you could try saving PP's to 2010 version.

Comment: PPT 2007 through current version all use the same file format, PPT is able to ignore any new features it doesn't understand when opening files from later versions.  The tool may or may not be able to do this.

Comment: I think the reason the Flowchart Converter wasn't updated after 2010 was because Microsoft added the "Group -> Ungroup" option to 2013 and beyond to make it all a simple copy/paste operation.  Right click the pasted image in Visio and select "Group -> Ungroup".

Answer (score 0):

I tried to go with that.
The tool requires Visio 2010 to be installed before you can continue. So, in case if you have Visio 2016 you will need to reinstall it to 2010 version first.